# WATCH command with pipes

Tags: pipe, watch

Hithere, how do I `watch` this command:
`netstat -plan|grep :80|egrep -v "(:8082)|(:8080)|(:8081)"|awk {'print $5'}|cut -d: -f 1|sort|uniq -c|sort -n`

It errors out when surrounding it with single/double quotes.

Comment: why can't you put the egrep pattern into single quotes, and then wrap the whole thing in double quotes for the watch?

Comment: it works, I can also escape the double quotes (forgot about escapes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
watch "netstat -plan|grep :80|egrep -v \"(:8082)|(:8080)|(:8081)\"|awk {'print $5'}|cut -d: -f 1|sort|uniq -c|sort -n"
```

You can also do it with single-quotes, but `\'` inside single quotes doesn't *actually* escape the single quote, so you end up having to replace every single-quote with `'\''`, which drives me nuts.